# Visiting Student for Graduate Studies in Mathematics

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, liberal-arts-colleges

All,

I am currently a student at a small liberal arts college which does not offer the courses that would make me more competitive as an applicant to Master's or PhD programs in Mathematics.

Since I am ready to move on, my first thought was to continue as a visiting (non-matriculated) student after graduation at a different university for one or two semesters before applying to programs.

It seems however, that few of the top universities have visiting students programs and most of the ones I've seen are geared toward undergraduates looking to go on exchange.

Does anyone know of programs aimed for people in my situation? Is it common? On NYU courant's site, for instance, they offer the non-degree option, but the major disadvantage is cost of living and lack of campus.

Thanks!

Comment: Voting to reopen.  OP does not need a recommendation of a specific program.  See my next comment.

Comment: You can take courses as a non-matriculated student at a wide variety of U.S. schools. New York City has a particularly high cost of living. You'll need to live off campus, and you may wish to consider working part time.  While working part time, two challenging courses is often a good fit, although of course this is very individual. If you take courses in a state university in the state where you have residency, the tuition will likely be lower than out-of-state tuition. Do look at a variety of states to compare tuition rates (make sure to consider Texas).

Comment: This really duplicates much of the question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/how-can-i-enter-into-the-mathematics-field-at-the-graduate-level-when-i-only-too