# Is there a way to do credited graduate level math courses (not a complete program just couple of specific courses)

Tags: graduate-school, education

I have completed my undergraduate (bachelor's of engineering) degree. I am looking to go for a masters, but I lack some prerequisite math courses on my transcript. Is there a way to get credited math courses (like stochastic calculus, probabilistic theory, etc.)?

I am from India, planning on applying mainly to european institutes. I have done good number of mathematical courses. But, lack only 2 courses for fulfilling the prerequisite. My planned universities dont have a pre master that I know of.

Note: The most important part is being able to get the credits and transcript. As I cannot share just a certificate. I havent been accepted. I need to complete the courses to meet the prerequisite for my application.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Particularly, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/8030/13240

Comment: I am from India, planning on applying mainly to european institutes. I have done good number of mathematical courses. But, lack only 2 courses for fulfilling the prerequisite. My planned universities dont have a pre master that I know of.

Comment: As my department chair once said, if we only accepted grad students who had all the prereqs, we wouldn't have a grad program. Check with the grad coordinator at the universities you are considering -- you may be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate. I vote to reopen based on the fact that this person is asking about a specific desire to take one-off courses (which are a “thing” at many good universities) and the current question doesn’t really treat these as an option.

Comment: Thanks, Dawn. one good answer could be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After being accepted to a University, typically you can take any class provided you meet the prerequisites of the class.

For example, after I graduated with my Bachelor's, I was bored at work.  I had learned Spanish (two years) in High School, and had lost some competency in speaking by not having used the language for years.

So I registered to take some undergraduate Spanish classes.  There were no problems at all.  Later I registered to take more Spanish, some public speaking (Communications dept), and a Microbiology class).  Again, not issues at all.

I was fortunate to still be living near my school upon graduation.  I imagine that once accepted, there is not general policy of "ejecting" you from the school upon graduation.  I would also imagine that such an acceptance wouldn't apply to graduate programs (which have their own acceptance policies) but at least in my school, one can take most classes without being registered in a degree program, provided you meet prerequisites.

I'd check your local Universities, especially the one you have graduated from.  I'm not sure how India handles these things, but there is a chance they have a similar policy.

Comment: I havent been accepted, I need to do the courses to meet the prerequisite.

Comment: I think the OP misread this answer. The poster is saying that after completing an undergrad degree, you are often allowed to pay a “non-degree seeking student fee” to take additional classes at your undergraduate institution or other schools. I did this when I was trying to get more courses before doing the PhD.

Comment: In my experience, I took grad courses which were “cross-listed” as undergraduate courses. So they were open to both undergrad and grad and therefore were acceptable to take as a “non-degree seeking” student.

Comment: That's helpful will enquire with my university. ANd did you get these non-degree courses after graduating ?

Comment: @Himanshuagarwal Yes, to clarify, since I've graduated, I've taken about 20 additional hours, not applied to any degree program, not even coordinated enough to be considered in a program (unless there's a program for Spanish speaking public presentations on microbiology :)  )

Comment: Thanks, @EdwinBuck